# Как задать квоты сайтам на одинаковом сервере?

Tags: php, mysql, centos, apache2, limits

Добрый день. Есть 1 сервер. Vpn. На нем 3 сайта example1.com, example2.com и example3.com

Как расставить им лимиты по потреблению cpu, ram и тд. 
Например я хочу чтобы example1.com не потреблял более 100M Ram в месяц. Пусть он работает медленно. Но чтобы example2.com мог потреблять аж 512M.

Надеюсь суть вопроса ясна.  Какие есть способы для реализации этого?

Сервак собран на centos. Там работает apache2 nginx mariadb и php7

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте это с помощью [Docker](https://www.docker.com) ([На русском](http://docker.cool/docs/))

Каждый сайт в отдельном докер-контейнере. Контейнеры позволяют [ограничить используемые ресурсы](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/).

**UPD:** т. к. у вас PHP и вам нужен лимит по оперативной памяти можете поставить каждому виртуальному хосту свой лимит памяти 
вот так `php_value memory_limit 2048M`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66054/discussion-on-answer-by-user3127286-------).